# How to properly add a value change listener to Map.Entry?

Tags: java, hashmap, overriding, extends

A project im working on currently requires me to ensure that while looping through a map's entries, if Entry.setValue is called, it would trigger a value change event. I see I can try something like adding a listener into an extension of the Map class on the .put method. My question is, would entries being changed trigger a listener in the map's put method? Or would I be forced to extend the Map.Entry class and stick listener logic into its setValue method?

Apologies in advance if this question is dumb - im new to using Maps in this way and a lot of the information ive seen so far has only lead to extending the Map itself, which seems easiest but i dont know if it would cover my case.

Comment: How are you looping in map, using Iterator? Cos it will throw concurrent modification exception if you update and iterate at same time

Comment: @NawnitSen – Not when you call `setValue()` on the Entry …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a pinch you could use the `PropertyChangeSupport` class. It makes managing `propertyChanges` very easy.  There's not much to tell here.  The parties that want to listen for changes register their listener with the map.  Then when the map modifies the value, the support fires off an event to all the listeners.  The values that are returned in the Event class may be altered to ones chosing.

```
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class PropertyChangeDemo implements PropertyChangeListener {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // leave static context of main
        new PropertyChangeDemo().start();
    }
    public void start() {
        MyMap<String,Integer> map = new MyMap<>();
        map.addMapListener(this);
        map.put("B",20);
        map.put("B",99);
        map.put("A",44);
        
        map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

Prints

```
source = map
oldValue = null
newValue = 20
source = map
oldValue = 20
newValue = 99
source = map
oldValue = null
newValue = 44
A=44
B=99
```

A listener for demonstration.

```
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent pce) {
        System.out.println("source = " + pce.getPropertyName());
        System.out.println("oldValue = " + pce.getOldValue());
        System.out.println("newValue = " + pce.getNewValue());
    }
    
}
```

The modified class

```
class MyMap<K,V> extends HashMap<K,V> {
        
    private PropertyChangeSupport ps = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

    // method to add listener
    public void addMapListener(PropertyChangeListener pcl) {
        ps.addPropertyChangeListener(pcl);
    }
    
    @Override 
     public V put(K key, V value) {
        V ret = super.put(key,value);
        ps.firePropertyChange("map", ret, value);
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Note:  There may be issues that have been missed in this simple solution.  Testing should be conducted before put into production use.  For one, there are many different ways to set an `Entry's` value.  This only does it when `put` is invoked, either by the user or indirectly by the map itself.

Answer (score 1):

`Map.Entry` is just an interface, so of course it would be possible to write an implementation of it that triggers a value change event to an `EventListener` instance that is registered to it or to the owning `Map` instance.

But I cannot see any way on how to convince any of the existing implementations of the interface `Map` to use that new implementation of `Entry` …

So you would end up in creating your own implementation of `Map` …

Alternatively, when you need that change listener *only when iterating* over the entry set, you can overwrite just the method `Map.entrySet()` of an appropriate implementation of `Map` that it will return a tweaked version of `Set` – tweaked in a way that the method `Set.iterator()` returns an `Iterator` instance whose method `Iterator.next()` returns your implementation of `Map.Entry` (wrapping the original one and delegating to its methods …) whose `setValue()` method will trigger the value change listener.

Something like this:

```
public class MyMapEntry<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V>
{
  private final Map.Entry<K,V> m_Wrapped;
  private final ChangeListener m_Listener;
  
  public MyMapEntry( ChangeListener listener, Map.Entry<K,V> entry ) 
  { 
    m_Listener = listener; 
    m_Wrapped = entry; 
  }
  
  @Override
  public void setValue( V value )
  {
    var event = new ChangeEvent( this, getValue(), value );
    m_Wrapped.setValue( value );
    m_Listener.sendEvent( event );
  }

  … // Implement the other methods
}

public class MyIterator<Map.Entry<K,V>> implements Iterator<Map.Entry<K,V>>
{
  private final Iterator<Map.Entry<K,V>> m_Iterator;
  private final ChangeListener m_Listener;

  public MyIterator( final ChangeListener listener, final Iterator<Map.Entry<K,V>> iterator )
  {
    m_Listener = listener;
    m_Iterator = iterator;
  }

  public Map.Entry<K,V> next()
  {
    return new MyMapEntry( m_Listener, m_Iterator.next() );
  }

  … // Delegation for all the other methods 
}

public class MySet<Map.Entry<K,V>> extends HashSet<Map.Entry<K,V>>  
{
  private final ChangeListener m_Listener;

  public MySet( ChangeListener listener, Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> other )
  {
    super( other );
    m_Listener = listener;
  }

  @Override
  public Iterator<Map.Entry<K,V>> iterator()
  {
    return new MyIterator( m_Listener, super.iterator() ); 
  }
}     

public class MyMap<K,V> extends HashMap<K,V>
{
  private final ChangeListener m_Listener;

  public MyMap( ChangeListener listener ) 
  { 
    super();
    m_Listener = listener; 
  }
  
  @Override
  public Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> entrySet()
  {
    return new MySet( listener, super.entrySet() );
  } 
}
```

This code is just a sketch, it may need some fixes before it runs!

That you copy the entry set in `MyMap.entrySet()` decouples your entry set from the original one; changes to the *structure* of the map will no longer be reflected to your set – but changes to the key values and the value values still do affect your set.